# Higher Order Components - React.JS

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Trying to pass initial value `10` to the Higher Order Components.

```
import HOC from './HighOrderComponent'

class ClickHandler extends Component{
  state= {val : 10}

  increment = () => {
    this.props.increment(this.state.val)
  }

  render(){
    return  <button onMouseOver={this.increment}>Mouse Over {this.props.value}</button>
  }
}
export default HOC(ClickHandler)
```

Here, I do not know how to use the `value` to update the state of

```
const HOC = (OriginalComponent) => {

  class HigherOrderComponent extends Component{

    state = { count : 0 }

    increment = (value) => {
      this.setState(prev => ( {count : prev.count + 1 }))
    }

    render(){
      return <OriginalComponent  value={this.state.count} increment={this.increment}/>
    }}

  return HigherOrderComponent
}
export default HOC
```

Expected Result: On load, Mover Over 10, once hovered, it will increment to 11, 12, 13.....

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your components is that `HOC` component's state overrode your `10` state defined in your `ClickHandler`.

If you changed `state = { count : 0 }` to `state = { count : 10 }` you will get the expected initial value of 10.

But seeing the code, what is the purpose of having state value maintained in both components? And the state value of `ClickHandler` is not even used by the HOC.

Guessing you want to maintain the state within `HOC` and simply wanted to pass in an initial value for it.

Would suggest the following changes:

```
class ClickHandler extends Component{
  // no need to maintain state again in `ClickHandler`
  // simply use the increment props for onMouseOver
  render(){
    return  <button onMouseOver={this.props.increment}>Mouse Over {this.props.value}</button>
  }
}

// add extra param for HOC to pass in initialValue of 10
export default HOC(ClickHandler, 10);


const HOC = (OriginalComponent, initialValue) => {

  class HigherOrderComponent extends Component{

    state = { count : initialValue }

    // no need to get the state value from `ClickHandler`
    increment = () => {
      this.setState(prev => ( {count : prev.count + 1 }))
    }

    render(){
      return <OriginalComponent  value={this.state.count} increment={this.increment}/>
    }}

  return HigherOrderComponent
}
```